# How can I use proper reference for a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, controller

I have 3 models. Projects has many Orderlines, and Orderlines has many Packages. I have a view with project_orderline as Show method where I render all packages as partial. It works fine, but when I add a new package I want to redirect_to (redirect back actually) the same view within the create action.

```
  class PackagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_package, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    orderline = project.orderlines.find(params[:orderline_id])
    @package = orderline.packages.new(package_params)

      if @package.save
        flash[:success] = "Package was successfully created."
        redirect_to project_orderline_path(orderline)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end
```

But I have the following error:

[ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PackagesController#create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYquv.png)

How should I fix this?

PS.: So, here is the error msg in textual format:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PackagesController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orderlines", :id=>nil, :orderline_id=>"18", :project_id=>#, origin: "123", project_id: 48, created_at: "2017-01-27 18:36:59", updated_at: "2017-01-27 18:36:59", subtotal: #>} missing required keys: [:id]

routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :orderlines do
     resources :packages
   end
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text of the error message.  This will make it a lot easier to answer and will make it easier for others with the same problem to find this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your `project_orderline_path(orderline)` is not working, but since you want to go back, you can do:

```
redirect_to :back
```

maybe you can post your routes, and the error as text in the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Correct, actually I want to go back and thanks, with :back it just works fine. However, I would like to understand why in the original way it cannot. Pls see my routes here at the post, I just edited.